# Prevent apache camel to move non qualified files to move to .camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am creating a simple file transfer utility where based on user input I search the file in the folder and transfer the matched file to destination. The problem
is camel is moving all the files which are not matching to .camel folder i dont want that to happen below is my snippet.

```
        from("file:C:\\input?noop=true;").
        filter(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME)
       .contains("xyz")).split(body().tokenize("\n")).
        streaming().bean(LineParser.class, "process").
        to("file:"+ Constants.getMapping().get(argumentName)+"? 
         fileExist=Append");
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You need to filter the file names directly in the from endpoint, see the include/exclude options in the file documentation how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the file component consumer options: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html. You should be able to use the "filter" or "filterFile" option in the from uri. These will filter at the endpoint, as Claus mentions above. The filterFile will be more concise if you are able to use the Simple language:

```
from("file:C:\\input?filterFile=...
```

Otherwise, you could create a filter bean to handle the filtering and use filter option to reference that bean. Notice that the filter().contains() is no longer needed:

```
from("file:C:\\input?filter=#someFileFilter")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
    .streaming()
    .bean(LineParser.class, "process")
    .to("file:"+ Constants.getMapping().get(argumentName)+"?fileExist=Append");

public class SomeFileFilter<T> implements GenericFileFilter<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {
        // return true if file should be included, false if excluded
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, went with generic filter as filter logic was bit complex.

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after noop=true and property will start working deprecating moving processed files to .camel

Processed files are all files processed without exception so even matched files will remain in C:\input directory too. When you use noop=true default idempotent repository is in-memory. So after you restart your app already processed files will be processed again. So you need create your own not in-memory idempotent repo.